# Aggregating data from multiple columns (similar to a PIVOT table)

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

I have a table that has the following data (shortened for this example):

```
    C1    C2    C3    C4
=========================
1   0     1     1     0
2   1     1     0     1
3   1     0     1     1
4   1     1     1     1
5   0     0     1     1
6   0     0     0     1
```

I want to create a create a query that gives me the following result:

```
    C3    C4
=============
C1   2     3 
C2   2     2
```

That is, the combination of those four columns when:

```
C1 = 1 & C3 = 1
C1 = 1 & C4 = 1
C2 = 1 & C3 = 1
C2 = 1 & C4 = 1
```

I've been able to get make some progress, but not ultimately what I want. I've managed to get this far: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d3d4/2/0

but I can't figure out how to get my query to format like my desired output above. I was going to try to use a `PIVOT` table, but quickly abandoned that idea because it seemed to get extremely convoluted once I needed to add a 2nd `PIVOT` statement (and I'd end up having to add more as my example above is a really basic example of the number of columns I need to  perform this on).

What am I missing?

Thank you.

Comment: I think you're going to need to first unpivot the table and then pivot it again the way you want it... (working in some example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT 'C1',SUM(CASE WHEN C1=1 AND C3=1 THEN 1 END)AS C3,
            SUM(CASE WHEN C1=1 AND C4=1 THEN 1 END)AS C4
FROM T1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'C2',SUM(CASE WHEN C2=1 AND C3=1 THEN 1 END)AS C3,
            SUM(CASE WHEN C2=1 AND C4=1 THEN 1 END)AS C4
FROM T1
```

## [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1a0ab/2)

Answer (score 1):

I think this gives you the result set as asked

```
SELECT COL1, C3, C4
FROM (
     SELECT SUBSTRING(col,1,2) col1, SUBSTRING(col,3,2) col2, value
     FROM (
           SELECT SUM(c1*c3) as c1c3, SUM(c1*c4) as c1c4, 
                  SUM(c2*c3) as c2c3, SUM(c2*c4) as c2c4
           FROM t1
          ) t 
     UNPIVOT (value FOR col IN (c1c3, c1c4, c2c3, c2c4)) AS u
    ) data
PIVOT (SUM(value) FOR col2 IN ([c3], [c4])) pvt
```

I started writing a query that gives the totals, the resultset looks like this

```
c1c3     c1c4     c2c3    c2c4
 2        3        2       2
```

At this moment you could probably just use this query and will get the result as wanted

```
SELECT 'c1' AS col, c1c3 AS C3, c1c4 AS C4
UNION ALL
SELECT 'c2' AS col, c2c3 AS C3, c2c4 AS C4
```

The first solution is just an example of how to UNPIVOT and then PIVOT again to order the columns in the way you want

Comment: Thanks for this. I chose Joe G Joseph's answer because it is more concise.